# Selenium code to scroll Horizontally in a web-element which is loading lazily

Tags: java, selenium

Can someone help me to write a selenium code to find an element inside div by scrolling horizontally when it (the element) is loading lazily.

For example in the following URL the elements are laoded after we scroll right :

1. http://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt/demo/horizontal.htm
2. http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_wide_container.html

I have tried :

```
 1. ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(<x-corodinate>,<y-coordinate>)");
 2. ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element); 
 3. ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(<x-corodinate>,<y-coordinate>)");
 4. ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

But was not solving my purpose.

I am using java 1.8 , selenium jar version is 3.0.1 and Firefox 50.0.2.

```
File driverPathFirefox = new File("PATH \\TO \\ Driver \\geckodriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",driverPathFirefox.getAbsolutePath()); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.navigate().to(URL);// URL could be the one referred in the question
WebElement scrollArea = driver.findElement(By.xpath(<Xpath of the div>));
// Capturing xpath of div from the URL referred above 
// xpath for div in http://ressio.github.io is "html/body/div[1]/div[2]"
// xpath for div in http://www.appelsiini.net is ".//*[@id='container']"

// Now here I need the code to scroll the web element horizontally 
// until desired element is visible.

driver.quit();
```

Selenium dependencies are :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try one of these (tested on your first [link](http://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt/demo/horizontal.htm)):

```
WebElement scrollArea = driver.findElement(By.className("wrapper"));

// Scroll to div's most right:
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft = arguments[0].offsetWidth", scrollArea);

// Or scroll the div by pixel number:
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft += 250", scrollArea);
```

In order to `scrollIntoView` you need the `element` to exist in the DOM, so maybe that's why it didn't work for you. As for the `window.scroll` you're trying to scroll the window and not inside an element.

Comment: Thanks. This solves the issue of scrolling horizontally. I came up with following code using you  suggested way. Can you please suggest the way to ensure END OF SCROLL area so that the function terminates even if desired element is not encountered till the end.

public static boolean stopScrollingIfElementExist(WebElement scrollArea,WebDriver driver) {
boolean exists = driver.findElements( By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/img[9]") ).size() != 0;
if(!exists){
   stopScrollingIfElementExist(scrollArea,driver);
  }
  return exists;

Comment: You can try `= arguments[0].scrollWidth` instead of `= arguments[0].offsetWidth`

Comment: None of the code above is solving my issue. Please help me to solve my issue.

Comment: I need something like this but scroll vertically a specific element. tried the following didn't work.               WebElement scrollArea = getElement("leftPanelEventsPage" );
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollUp = arguments[0].offsetHeight", scrollArea);
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollUp += 250", scrollArea);

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement scrollArea = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"products-index-pane\"]/div[3]/div/div"));

    // Scroll to div's most right:
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft = arguments[0].offsetWidth", scrollArea);
```

Comment: Please try to add some sort of explanation alongside answers. This may be great code offering the perfect solution, but without some explanation it lacks any supporting evidence and makes it hard for others to learn what is going on or even generally learn for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void scrollRightAndLeft() {
        // Give the xpath of the element to which you have to scroll

        WebElement scroll_right = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
        WebElement scroll_left = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));

        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        
        // Scroll Right
        jse.executeScript("argument[0].scrollIntoView()", scroll_right);
        
        // Scroll Left
        jse.executeScript("argument[0].scrollIntoView()", scroll_left);
    }
```